# Copy submatrix to another matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Qw matrix that is 4x4.
I want to copy its upper 3x3 matrix to another matrix called R.
I did it manually, but I am wondering if there is a smarte way to do it.
I used copyTo and pushback, but did not work. I am using OpenCV 2.4.5 in c++

```
Qw.row(0).copyTo(R.row(0));
Qw.row(1).copyTo(R.row(1));
Qw.row(2).copyTo(R.row(2));
```

Or:

```
R.push_back(Qw.row(0));
R.push_back(Qw.row(1));
R.push_back(Qw.row(2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Qw` and `R` are both `cv::Mat`, you could use a mask:

```
R = Qw(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3));
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you. Do you know how can I do the reverse procedure, e.g. Fill a matrix 4*4 like Qw with a 3*3 R matix (upper left) and a 3*1 column matrix (4th column). The last row could be filled e.g. with zeros.

Comment: Hmm.. Seems that the Qw matrix Qw= Mat::zeros(4,4, CV_32FC1) remains filled with zeros and not with the values of R.

Comment: In OpenCV 2.4: `Qw = cv::Mat::zeros(4,4,CV_8U);` and then `R.copyTo(Qw(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)));`. It works fine!

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. What about copying just one row/column though?

Comment: You just have to set correctly the mask (see `cv::Rect` documentation) and use a ROI: `cv::Mat R_ROI = R(cv::Rect(0,0,3,1));` and then `R_ROI.copyTo(Qw(cv::Rect(0,0,3,1)));`.